# Wordpress Unload Plugin For Single Page Load

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have some custom pages that are not part of wordpress, but they tap into the Wordpress theme by calling `wp_load.php`. I want to be able to disable a few plugins, like hit counters etc so they dont waste any server resources on pages that have no use for them at all.

This post covers turning them off using code https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/disable-plugin-plugin-action-via-theme , but this isnt what i want to do. I want to keep all of them enabled on the website, for the specific pages that only tap into the theme, I want to disable certain plugins to help performance.

So far my only solution is to unload all of the hooks, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Conditional Deactivation of Plugins
*/

/* This must be installed as a must use plugin */

add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function( $plugins ) {
    return array_filter( $plugins, function( $plugin ) {
        return ! ( *some condition on $_REQUEST* && in_array( $plugin, [ *list of plugins to exclude* ] ) );
    } );
} );
```

The list of active plugins are stored as the option 'active_plugins'. This works by modifying the return value of get_option( 'active_plugins' ). Since, the call to get_option( 'active_plugins' ) is done very early in load process this filter cannot be installed in a normal plugin or in the theme's functions.php as that code runs after the call to get_option( 'active_plugins' ). However, must use plugins are loaded before the call to get_option( 'active_plugins' ).

The return value of get_option('active_plugins' ) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => google-analytics-for-wordpress/googleanalytics.php
    [1] => nggtags-for-wp-media-library/nggtags-for-wp-media-library-loader.php
    [2] => wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php
)
```